# JSP changes are not being reflected in RAD and websphere

Tags: jsp, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I am using RAD 6.0 with websphere 6.1 version. What ever the changes i have done for the jsps are not being reflected. I tested it by writing some system.out.println also. 
Many times i clean and build the workspace. What i observed is that when i have seen the following path :

C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv13.3-dev3-1\temp\KK9387Node11\server1\AstroWEBEAR\AstroWEB.war

I have found few _xxx.class files which are compiles jsp pages on 23rd april 2013. I have deleted those compiled .class files today ie on 16th may 2013, and clean build the workspace and when i hit the 
url i found the _xxx.class files are generated with 23rd april 2013 only but not on 16th may 2013 (which is current date). I am not understanding where the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried removing the application from the server, stopping the server, adding it back, and restarting?